# Extract multiple specific XML attributes using PHP

Tags: php, xml

I'm trying to extract several attributes from an XML file generated by a piece of software but I'm having no luck.

The code I have so far looks like this;

```
$xml_feed_url = 'http://localhost/rest/getNowPlaying.view?u=USERNAMEt&p=PASSWORD&v=1.8.0&c=test';  
$ch = curl_init();  
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $xml_feed_url);  
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, false);  
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);  
$xml = curl_exec($ch);  
curl_close($ch); 
echo $xml;
```

This code successfully outputs the following XML file;

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<subsonic-response xmlns="http://subsonic.org/restapi" status="ok" version="1.8.0">  
  <nowPlaying>  
    <entry id="1805" parent="1798" title="Too Close" album="The Lateness Of The Hour" artist="Alex Clare" isDir="false" coverArt="1798" created="2012-05-22T13:12:29" duration="256" bitRate="320" track="4" discNumber="1" year="2011" genre="Pop" size="10283678" suffix="mp3" contentType="audio/mpeg" isVideo="false" path="Alex Clare/The Lateness Of The Hour/Alex Clare - Too Close.mp3" albumId="50" artistId="14" type="music" username="RestClient" playerId="8" minutesAgo="0"/>  
    <entry id="33664" parent="33642" title="Hot Ride" album="Always Outnumbered, Never Out Gunned" artist="The Prodigy" isDir="false" coverArt="33642" created="2012-05-10T00:31:16" duration="276" bitRate="128" track="5" discNumber="1" year="2004" genre="Other" size="5135448" suffix="mp3" contentType="audio/mpeg" isVideo="false" path="The Prodigy/Always Outnumbered, Never Out Gunned/The Prodigy - Hot Ride.mp3" albumId="2064" artistId="635" type="music" username="Revenant" playerId="6" playerName="test" minutesAgo="3"/>  
  </nowPlaying>  
</subsonic-response>
```

I'm able to successfully extract specific attributes using a foreach loop (below), but I'm looking to extract specific multiple attributes from one user rather than them all.

```
foreach($xml->children()->children() as $second_gen){  
echo "User: ".$second_gen['username'];  
echo "Artist: ".$second_gen['artist'];  
echo "Title: ".$second_gen['title'];  
echo "Album: ".$second_gen['album'];
```

Any ideas would be appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: who decided to have so many attributes?

Comment: The guy who made [Subsonic](http://www.subsonic.org/)

Comment: What prevents you to filter the elements according to an attribute value? And actually what does qualify an attribute being from one user? How would you decide that? (sorry, not firm with subsonic, just XML).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about using simple_xml and XPath?

Something like...

```
$username='Revenant';
$xml->registerXPathNamespace("n", "http://subsonic.org/restapi");
$result=$xml->xpath("//n:entry[@username='$username']/@title | //n:entry[@username='$username']/@album | //n:entry[@username='$username']/@artist");

echo "$result[0] by $result[2] on the album $result[1]";
```

Tested with PHP 5.4.4

Michi

Comment: Thank you! This fits my needs perfectly.  
The reason I wasn't using simplexml originally was because it was giving a "Start tag expected, '<' not found" error, so I went with using curl, going using `simplexml_load_file` instead of `simplexml_load_string` made this work. (I don't understand why as I swear I tried both before deciding to use curl.